# Como realizar salto de linea desde los datos de mi base de datos

Tags: html

tengo unos registros en una base de datos donde estos mismos registros los muestro por medio de html, pero quiero realizar un salto de linea desde mi registro en la bd, por ejemplo este es uno de mis registros:

```
4 filetes de pescado blanco<br>1 cebolla en medias lunas<br>4 c de jitomates guajes, picados y sin cáscara<br>3 dientes de ajo<br>de taza de alcaparras'
```

asi luce en mi gestor de base de datos :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les asigno br en mi registro para que en mi html me haga este salto de linea, pero no me funciona me lo imprime de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo donde imprimo mi registro, estoy usando angular y mi bd es en mysql:

```
                <div class="col texto">
                    {{Receta.ingredientes1}}
                </div>
```

es decir que no respeta los br asignados en mi registro

Reemplace el br por \n y no me funciono, gracias.

Comment: Amigo muestra mas detalles de tu código por que probé lo que intentas y me funciono.

Comment: Si ya actualice la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato tiene el campo de tu tabla?, normalmente cuando quieres guardar tags html en una BD, los campos deben ser TEXT y no VARCHAR

Comment: ¿Qué lenguaje estás usando en el servidor?, si es PHP y Laravel (Blade), revisa la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data) para saber cómo enviar los datos sin que sean escapados (convirtiendo caracteres especiales a entidades HTML)

Comment: El tipo de dato que en mi columna es text, y utilizo una api de adonis con el lenguaje JavaScript, y de front-end angular con TypeScript , gracias.